Ask a question on the norm of linear transformation
The below is from a book that I am reading:
If $X$ and $Y$ are normed linear spaces we showed in Lemma 4.14 that $B(X, Y)$ is a vector space. We now show that $B(X, Y)$ is also a normed space. While doing this we often have as many as three different norms, from three different spaces, in the same equation, and so we should in principle distinguish between these norms. In practice we simply use the symbol $\|\cdot\|$ for the norm on all three spaces as it is still usually easy to determine which space an element is in and therefore, implicitly, to which norm we are referring. To check the axioms for the norm on $B(X, Y)$ that we will define in Lemma 4.15 we need the following consequence of Lemma 4.1
$\sup \{\|T(x)\|:\|x\| \leq 1\}=\inf \{k:\|T(x)\| \leq k\|x\|$ for all $x \in X\}$
and so in particular $\|T(y)\| \leq \sup \{\|T(x)\|:\|x\| \leq 1\}\|y\|$ for all $y \in X$.
Question: Given the first equality, why we have $\|T(y)\| \leq \sup \{\|T(x)\|:\|x\| \leq 1\}\|y\|$ for all $y \in X$?

If $K=\min{k:\lVert Tx\rVert\leq k\lVert x\rVert\text{ for all }x\in X}$, then by definition $\lVert Tx\rVert\leq K\lVert x\rVert$ for all $x\in X$. But by the equality, $K=\sup_{\lVert x\rVert\leq 1}\lVert Tx\rVert$.

The comment about $| |$ with no decoration (such as a subscript 2) is important- in reading this book you'll need to be careful about what norm is being used in each section.  Some other authors use the convention that if $| |$ appears without any decoration then the argument is true for all norms.

@Lorago but here is the infimum, not the minimum.

The set is closed (easily checked), non-empty (as $T$ is assumed bounded), and bounded below (by $0$), so the infimum is attained, i.e. it is a minimum

If $\|T\|=\sup\{\|T(x)\|:\|x\|\le1\}$,
what is true is that for each $y\in X$ we have $T(y/\|y\|)\le \|T\|$
then $$\|T(y)\|\le\|T\|\|y\|,$$
relation which links the three norms involved.
